# Single Sign On Shopify

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, shopify, single-sign-on

We currently have an e-commerce website with a bunch of other features so accounts are necessary.

We're moving over the store over to Shopify but currently customers have to login on our website, then again on the shop. I've been unable to find any Single Sign On documentation, what would be the best solution?

I was considering making the login form post to both our back-end and Shopify to trick Shopify into creating a session but i'm not sure how reliable it'd be.

The website is PHP & MySQL.

Comment: If they are on the same domain and same mysql server I would set a cookie and either logins and check if it exist before redirecting to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Single sign-on is available but only in Enterprise plans. You need to contact Shopify for these plans and access to single sign-on.